# Package do not import correctly in project

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, package

I recently created a Typescript Package that I would like to test in an app before publishing on NPM.

The entry file (index.ts) looks like this  =>

```
import Builder from './core/builder';

export default Builder;
```

Basically, there is many files, but I want the user to just use a "static" class `Builder` that I export in the index. so the user can just do `import Builder from 'builderts'`

My `package.json` folder is the following

```
  "name": "builderts",
  "main": "./dist/builderts.js",
  "types": "./dist/builderts.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "preversion" : "npm run lint",
    "prepare": "npm run build",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm test && npm run lint",
    "version" : "npm run format && git add -A src",
    "postversion" : "git push && git push --tags",
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc-watch",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"src/**/*.js\"",
    "lint": "eslint tsconfig.json"
  },
```

and my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
      "module": "amd",                          /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
      "declaration": true,                      /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
      "declarationMap": true,                   /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
      "sourceMap": true,                        /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
      "outFile":"./dist/builderts.js",              /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
      "outDir": "dist",                         /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
      "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
      "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

The problem I face is, I tried to create a small test project and install the module using

`npm install absolute/path`

it install correctly, but when I try to import the package using

`import Builder from 'builderts';`

I do not have neither autocompletion, and I have an error saying

> File 'D:/User/Local/gitRepo/builderts/dist/builderts.d.ts' is not a module.

I do not quite understand what I am missing in the process.

Comment: If you check the `node_modules` folder, do you see the `builderts` item? Can you try to uninstall and use `npm pack` (from builderts) and `npm install <tarball file> ` (inside your test project)? Usually npm has famous issues with local packages and symlinking

Comment: Is it possible to provide `builderts.d.ts` file (or even part of it)? It might be that your bundled file isn't module so you can't import something from it. Does this file exists?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you need to update the `types` in `package.json`

You stated above that the file name was `index.ts`, have you considered updating `package.json` ? :

```
{ 
...
"types": "./dist/index.ts",
...
}
```

Comment: `index.ts` is the entry of the app yes, but when built it in `./dist/builderts.d.ts` But yes is something wrong with type file, I checked some library in ts and they do not use the `"declaration": true, `